# Is it possible to hook into the search crawler process, so that the crawled content can be transferred to a 3rd party indexing solution?

Tags: 2013, search, 2016, crawling

I'd like to hook on the existing search crawler process in SP 2013 and 2016 to use a 3rd party indexing and search solution. As a second step this index should be searchable by SharePoint as well.

I know the question is pretty unspecific, I just want to know if it is at all possible and what in general need to be done. Do I have to implement my own crawler? What's the keyword I can search for to get in depth information? The information I found were only on how to add 3rd party content to the SharePoint search. I'd like to do the opposite. Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Well best point to start would be the 3rd Party indexing solution documentation. If it doesn't have an example how to index Sharepoint (which is one of most popular DMS\ECM) then I wouldn't bother with it and just move to Elastic Search.

Comment: @Marek Sared: Well. I want to develop a SharePoint connector, that's the point. The solution is not SharePoint-aware yet.

Comment: What is the product? You could try CEWS, but it is not really built for this. Does your solution have a crawler that can process web sites?

Comment: No it has no crawler, it is basically a service which indexes content given by post requests (very simplified).